# Which model is more efficient and why?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

Suppose, I have two NN models:

1. CNN model
2. Sequential NN model

They are solving the same problem. The data points have the same number of features.

In the case of #1, we used 0.6 million data points, 35k epochs, and the model achieved 80% accuracy in the training.

In the case of #2, we used 1.4 million data points, 1k epochs, and the model achieved 90% accuracy in the training.

Which model is better/more efficient and why?

Comment: You quote "% accuracy in the training". Could you clarify how this was measured - is it reported accuracy on the training dataset, the best result from cross-validation, or a final report against a hold-out test dataset?

Comment: @norbertk, I got the answer to my query. thanks.